# How to write a running total based on criteria in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm building a report which gives me the total count of unique accounts within a calendar month.
However, this total is based on the number of active accounts (accounts subscribed to a service), and once their contract ends they will be excluded from the total count.

For example, Company A has subscribed to the service on 1/1/2018 and their contract ends on 1/1/2020. So Company A should be included in the total count of unique accounts for all the months their under contract until their contract ends.

End Result would look something like this:

[image]

Here is the SQl query that I have so far. How can I write the code such that it will give me this cumulative/running total. I added the columns for reference.

```
SELECT A.Name, CA.Name, CA.Start_Date__c, CA.End_Date__c, CA.Product_Code_CPQ__c
FROM    [salesforce].[Client_Asset__c] AS CA
INNER JOIN salesforce.Account AS A
    ON CA.Account__c = A.Id
WHERE  Product_Code_CPQ__c IN(
'DSWPSTRSUB','DSWPESSSUB','DSWPPROSUB','DSWPHOSTSUB','DSWPMULTIHOSTSUB','DSWPOLXWRAPFPE',
'DSWPOLXWRAPSUB','WPCALENDARFORALT','WPCALHOSTINGBUN','IMWPTM','SBWPRET','SBWPRETNR','WORDPLUMWEBSUCCESS',
'WORDPWEBSUCCESS','WORDPOGS','FDSTRWORDPDESGNSUB','FDWPFPE','WORDPEMERGHOST','WORDPSUBBUN','WPOLXPLUGIN',
'POSTSTARTWORDPAF','POSTWORDPSTARTBUN','LUMWORDPSSUBBUN','WORDPLUMOGS','LUMFDSTRWPDESGNSUB',
'LUMPSTWORDPSTRBUN','LUMPOSTSTRTWORDPAF','FDWPEMERGFPE')
AND End_Date__c > GETDATE()
AND Active__c = 1
```

Comment: Which version of Sql Server? Windowing functions can [make this easier](https://learnsql.com/blog/what-is-a-running-total-and-how-to-compute-it-in-sql/), but if you're using a very old version they aren't available yet.

Comment: I'm using version 13.0.5865.1

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp ([month] INT, [group] VARCHAR(10), [value] REAL)


INSERT INTO #tmp ([month], [group], [value]) VALUES 
(1, 'A', 1), (2, 'A', 5), (3, 'A', 3), (4, 'A', 2), (5, 'A', 8),
(1, 'B', 7), (2, 'B', 3), (3, 'B', 2), (4, 'B', 4), (5, 'B', 6)


SELECT c.[month], c.[group], c.current_total, r.running_total
FROM 
(
    SELECT [month],[group], SUM([value]) current_total
    FROM #tmp 
    GROUP BY [month],[group]
) C JOIN 
(
    SELECT [month],[group], SUM([value]) OVER (partition BY [group] ORDER BY                  [month]) running_total
    FROM #tmp 
) R ON C.[month]=R.[month] AND C.[group]=R.[group]
ORDER BY 2,1
```

Tested on mssql 2016. Handle potential missing values yourself.